# Android Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS not found

Tags: java, android

I want to adjust display settings in my activity.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS);             
startActivity(intent);
```

but i am getting following exception:

```
09-24 21:24:35.901: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5892): 
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
    No Activity found to handle Intent 
        { action=android.settings.DISPLAY_SETTINGS }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should :

```
try {
    final Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // not sure if needed
    startActivity(i);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // not much you can do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Intent **Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS** works fine with Android **SDK 1.6**. *[Atleast for me.]*
But then the [documentation](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~linuxsoft/android/android-0.9_beta/docs/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS) states
*"In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this."*